# How to use Satang "orders/user" API with java?

Tags: java, http

I've built java code to use satang "orders/user" api.
But got 405 error.
Please help me.
I've built placeLimitOrder() function.
And used successfully.
Then getUserOrders() function also made with same rult.
But this function got 405 error.
I can't find the reason.

public String getUserOrders (String pair,String limit,String offset,String status,String side) 
{

```
    String req="limit="+limit+"&offset="+offset+"&pair="+pair+"&side="+side+"&status="+status;
    String operation="orders/user";
    String signature=getSignature(req);
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl+operation);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput( true );
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "TDAX-API "+this.key);
    con.setRequestProperty("Signature",signature);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java client");
    con.setUseCaches( false );

    JsonObject obj=new JsonObject();
    obj.addProperty("limit", limit);
    obj.addProperty("offset", offset);
    obj.addProperty("pair", pair);
    obj.addProperty("side", side);
    obj.addProperty("status", status);

    String json=obj.toString();

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(json);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();

    if(responseCode!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        throw new BadResponseException(responseCode);
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

Following code working well.
I can't find the reason.

```
public String placeLimitOrder(String amount,String pair,String price,String side) throws IOException, BadResponseException
{
    Long lnonce=new Date().getTime();
    String nonce=lnonce.toString();
    String req="amount="+amount+"&nonce="+nonce+"&pair="+pair+"&price="+price+"&side="+side+"&type=limit";
    String operation="orders/";
    String signature=getSignature(req);
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl+operation);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setDoOutput( true );
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );

    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "TDAX-API "+this.key);
    con.setRequestProperty("Signature",signature);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java client");
    con.setUseCaches( false );

    JsonObject obj=new JsonObject();
    obj.addProperty("amount", amount);
    obj.addProperty("nonce", nonce);
    obj.addProperty("pair", pair);
    obj.addProperty("price", price);
    obj.addProperty("side", side);
    obj.addProperty("type", "limit");
    String json=obj.toString();

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(json);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();

    if(responseCode!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        throw new BadResponseException(responseCode);
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getUserOrders(String pair,String limit,String offset,String status,String side) throws IOException, BadResponseException
{
    String req="limit="+limit+"&offset="+offset+"&pair="+pair+"&side="+side+"&status="+status;
    String operation="orders/user?"+req;
    String signature=getSignature("");
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl+operation);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setDoOutput( true );
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );

    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "TDAX-API "+this.key);
    con.setRequestProperty("Signature",signature);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java client");
    con.setUseCaches( false );

    int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();

    if(responseCode!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        throw new BadResponseException(responseCode);
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you are trying to do *GET* to https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/user
Headers should include:

- Signature
- Authentication

Query Parameters:

- pair
- limit
- offset
- status
- side

From your code, it looks like you have put everything to the Signature.

[Link to API docs](https://docs.satang.pro/apis/private/orders)

**This is what you should fix:**

1. URL. It should look like:

https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/user?pair=pairValue&limit=limitValue&offset=... add all the parameters and insert values.

2. Change request method to `GET`
3. Double-check your headers (Signature, Authentication).

Error code 405 - "bad request", which means most likely your request URL is bad. After you will fix URL, you should be able to get a different response code like 403/401 which should indicate that something is wrong with signature or authentication. In the best-case scenario, you will get 200 and then try to parse the JSON response.

Also, I don't recommend you to use `HttpURLConnection`,  Generally, it’s NOT recommended to use this class, because the codebase is very old and outdated, it may not supports the new HTTP/2 standard, in fact, it’s really difficult to configure and use this class. Please consider using *OkHttp*, *Apache HttpClient* or other libraries.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. Then your answer is for create order. Have you any experience in satang api? If then, i hope to discuss about satang api.

Comment: I don't have experience in satang. I just googled it by your code, because you have not included any documentation. If your code is about _orders/user_ then you should do `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: I've tried to use "GET" just now. But got same result. 405 error.

Comment: There are many things wrong with your request. Please try to fallow one of _GET_  [examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)